# CSS :hover @keyframes animation makes the image flicker

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animation and I have applied it to one of the `html` element just fine, but then when I applied the same animation on hover to another element(img) it just keep on flickering.

My CSS

```
.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}
.logo {
  height: 35px;
}
.logo-box:hover {
  animation: moveInRight 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

`.logo-box` is absolute to the `.header` class

My HTML body

```
<body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="logo-box">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo-white.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="text-box">
        <h1 class="heading-primary">
          <span class="heading-primary-main">Outdoors</span>
          <span class="heading-primary-sub">is where life happends</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Can anybody help me out fixing this...

Comment: Does the flickering occur in every browser or just Chrome?

Comment: @Dai Not sure, I have only tried chrome and edge which is chromium so I guess that makes no difference. I'm kinda new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay to the start of the animation.

```css
.logo-box:hover {
  animation: moveInRight 1s ease-in 0.5s;
  /*the 0.5s is the delay*/
}
```

Explanation if you want to know whats going on:

This is a well known problem that is actually related to UX. The flicker problem is because of the opacity. As soon as a `:hover` occurs (event triggered) the opacity goes to zero. Now as you take your pointer to the image, multiple `hover` events are triggered due to micro movements of pointer. One hover event ends and second is triggered. CSS stops animating as soon as `hover` is ended and `opacity` gets to `100%` and the second `hover` event causes it to go to `0` right away which is the `flicker`. If you add some delay then the mouse would get stable and then the animation will be played.

CSS, yet, isn't offering any way to complete the animation once `hover` is triggered i.e. no matter if the pointer is no more on the element, animation must be completed.